# I think comments should allow more characters on Code Review

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments

I just got a great code review and I wanted to reply to it because I had questions. Of course the character limit was exceeded very fast.

Code reviews are somewhat different in it's nature than the content on other Stack Exchange sites. I'm sure the average character count per user submission is much higher.

If it is not intended to discuss the code but let the reviews stand for themselves then maybe I'm wrong but I felt the urge to write huge text in reply and I couldn't.

Since the site is still beta, I wonder if you might take this into consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have that many questions then a single comment isn't really the right place to post them. I don't think that there is an ideal solution to this though.

You could:

- update your question - not ideal.
- post an answer - better, but again not ideal.
- break each question/point into a separate comment.
- take the questions into chat.

Breaking the comment down will trigger the "too many comments, take this to chat" message so chat is probably your best approach. However you do need a minimum of 20 reputation to participate in chat.

Comment: Well it's not that hard to get 20rep I guess. But it's not only about questions but also about posting refactored source code, or discussion. I mean it's doable to reduce my writing, strip down long praises and thankyous. But it kinda sucks writing about sourcecode in SMS-sytle. kkthxbye :)

Comment: @unR - if you have more source code then you should probably be updating your question, or posting a new question.

Comment: okay I see, there is a current *workaround* for all of this. So working around is what I'll do. accepted.